# Problem with bibliography with "uiucthesis2009"

Tags: bibliographies

I am using ["uiucthesis2009"](https://github.com/bardsoftware/template-thes-uiuc) to prepare my thesis, but I have trouble to use bibliography with that package. In particular, the following MWE does not produce any bibliography at all

```
\documentclass[edeposit,fullpage]{uiucthesis2009}

\begin{document}

\cite{he2019kramers}

\backmatter
\bibliography{thesisbib}


\end{document}
```

On the other hand, the following indeed produces the desired citation

```
\documentclass[edeposit,fullpage]{revtex4-2}

\begin{document}

\cite{he2019kramers}

\backmatter
\bibliography{thesisbib}


\end{document}
```

What I did is to upload the .sty and .cls files onto overleaf, and use the packages there. I suspect that there maybe some problems with these two files, or I have misused them. Since I am not sure how to read these two files, if anyone can help to spot the problem I would be more than grateful!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thank you!  @Mensch

Comment: you always need a \bibliographystyle{...} command to tell bibtex how to generate teh bibliography (you presumably got an error message from bibtex)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh my... How can I forgot that...  But why revtex4-2 works?

Comment: revtex calls that by default  as far as I remember